# Mongodb Query for substring?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, time

My database is in this format

```
{
  "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000002"),
  "date": "01/05/2020",
  "post": "some random post 2",
  "time": "11:07:42 AM",
  "username": "random user 2"
}, 
{
  "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000002"),
  "date": "01/05/2020",
  "post": "some random post 2",
  "time": "11:07:42 PM",
  "username": "random user 2"
},
```

I would like to query only time which have a PM field so my data should be returned to only this

```
{
  "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000002"),
  "date": "01/05/2020",
  "post": "some random post 2",
  "time": "11:07:42 PM",
  "username": "random user 2"
},
```

TIME here is a string and I would like to substring to the PM part but some time TIME is like `7:38:43 PM` so it should remove any whitespace also

Please help thanks

Comment: Could you please share your current query that is not working for you? Add the code in your main post, not in the comment pls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do this is to use a simple [regex](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/):

```
collection.find({ time: { $regex: "PM"} } , function(err,result){ ... })
```

Comment: thanks its working but how can I have it working with another regex ? Like I have a regex with date too like 

db.collection.find({
  date: {
    $regex: "\/05\/2020"
  },
  time: {
    $regex: "PM"
  }
})

Invidually its working fine but along with it is returning no document found

Comment: Hm, this should be fine, as your regex-expressions operate on two different fields returning a document only if date matches "05/2020" and time matches "PM". Can you add sample data which does not work with the two regex combined?

Comment: its working now I had some problems with the sample data thanks man!